# A server with the specified hostname could not be found Error In IOS

Tags: ios, .net, iphone, web-services

I Got below error in my Xcode 6.1.1 when i fetch data from .net webservice

"A server with the specified hostname could not be found"

I am using wi-fi network and simulator for same.

This webservice is work fine in Android but it only gives error in IOS

I dont know why this error is occur.This problem is from webservice server side or IOS side?

Please give advice

Answer (score 0):

Try this : open the simulator, click on iOS Simulator on the menu, then Reset Content and Settings, and re-run you application.

Regards